# R Shiny: Using assign() to compose the name of reactive output elements fails

Tags: r, button, shiny, output, reactive

What I am trying to achieve is to handle dynamically generated UI elements with names based on a counter that is triggered on a button click. This works fine, but I cannot compose the names of these output elements using assign(). Here is a simple example that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run_btn", "Run"),
  plotOutput('Plot1'),
  plotOutput('Plot2'),
  plotOutput('Plot3')
)

server <- function(input, output, clientData, session) {
  observeEvent(input$run_btn, {
    myplot <- renderPlot({
      boxplot(1:100)
    })   
    assign(paste('output$Plot', sep = "", input$run_btn), myplot) # DOES NOT WORK!
    # output$Plot1 <- myplot # THIS WORKS!
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try ```output[[paste0("Plot", input$run_btn)]] <- myplot```.

Comment: Is it because you don't specify for `envir = ` in your assign function. When I have used `assign` I have always had to specify `envir = GlobalEnv`, but I havn't used it with shiny and don't know what environment you would need to specify.

Comment: Here is a link to another forum that discusses this topic: https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-environments-in-shiny/62154

Comment: `assign` is usually the wrong answer in general, it can get even more confusing and *wrong* in a `shiny`/reactive project.

Comment: This question is interesting, but I don't see the actual utility in using `input$run_btn` to identify the target plot: after your third button press, the app stops updating any plots. Perhaps you can provide a little more context to explain why that seems like a good idea?

Comment: This is just some demo code to illustrate the problem. In my app I generate a new plot every time the button is pressed. The suggestion of @NiklasvMoers  ```output[[paste0("Plot", input$run_btn)]] <- myplot``` seemed to do the trick! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I agree with @r2evans that I don't see the purpose of assigning each plot to an individual input field. However, I have used this trick in the past to avoid typo bugs (which can be really difficult to fix in a large shiny project): You assign the inputId to a variable so that you get an object not found error when misspelling an ID.

Comment: Thanasis, that's good context. To me that suggests that you should react to the button press with `insertUI(...); output[[newid]] <- renderPlot(...);`, and then possibly at some point clean up by `removeUI(...)`ing the older plots (or keep them around, why not).

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that you want to stack new plots in some fashion, additive, potentially with some cleanup?

Actions:

- Press the `Run` button, it creates a plot of `mtcars` with a random car highlighted.
- Repeat this multiple times, each time a new plot is added, stacked before/above all other plots.
- Press the `Trim` button, and all plots except the most-recent are removed from the UI completely.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("trim_btn", "Trim"),
  actionButton("run_btn", "Run")
)

someplot <- function(nm) {
  rand <- sample(nrow(mtcars), size = 1)
  plot(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars, main = paste(nm, "-", rownames(mtcars)[rand]), pch = 16, cex = 1)
  points(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars[rand,,drop=FALSE], pch = 16, cex = 2, col = "red")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  idcount <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$run_btn, {
    thisid <- idcount() + 1
    idcount(thisid)
    thisid <- paste0("plot", thisid)
    insertUI(selector = "#run_btn", where = "afterEnd",
             ui = plotOutput(thisid))
    output[[thisid]] <- renderPlot({ someplot(thisid) })
  })
  observeEvent(input$trim_btn, {
    curid <- idcount() - 1
    if (curid > 0) {
      selectors <- paste0("#plot", seq_len(curid))
      # this could be improved to only remove existing selectors
      for (sel in selectors) removeUI(selector = sel)
    }
  })
}

# # Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```